# Get Field names and values from entity when saved or changed C# .net 3.5

Tags: c#, entity-framework

[image]I have got this piece of code which gets fields names from an entity

```
 public static string ObjectToNotes(object obj)
    {
        if (obj == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("obj", "Value can not be null or Nothing!");
        }

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        Type t = obj.GetType();
        PropertyInfo[] pi = t.GetProperties();

        for (int index = 0; index < pi.Length; index++)
        {
            sb.Append(pi[index].Name + "=" + pi[index].GetValue(obj, null));

            if (index < pi.Length - 1)
            {
                sb.Append(Environment.NewLine);
            }
            MessageBox.Show(sb.ToString());
        }

        return sb.ToString();
    }
```

I need to adapted this cause its not bringing through values from look-up tables that have been referenced its just bringing the code number of the drop down value as we want the text to be stored. Does anyone know how to do this via generics so that I dont have to trap all lookup codes individually.

In case you wondering the application is for an audit trail

ALSO Is their a way to get old values from an entity.

If you look at the screen shot below it is pulling through the data  but the reason field is a referenced lookup as you see has the value 22 instead of the description appearing which is what it should

Comment: don't quite understand your intentions can you add some usages and describe problems a little more

Comment: @GuruStron added screen shot